# Google Guava: Predicate assertTrue

Tags: java, guava

I am looking for a method to assure all objects contained in a `Collect` (`List`) return a specified value from a predicate.

Pseudo Code:

```
Collections.assertTrue(List<Ballons>, isBluePredicate)
```

I do not see this being possible with the current API (maybe I am not looking in the proper place)

If this does exist would the function exit when it first encounters a false value?

Answer (score 5):

The [Iterables.all(Iterable, Predicate)](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#all%28java.lang.Iterable,%20com.google.common.base.Predicate%29) method is the normal way to do this; the assertion would need to be your own.

Answer (score 2):

Guava itself does not have any asserts. If I understand the question right you should be able to use [Iterables.all](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/index.html?com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html)

```
assert Iterables.all(balloonsList, isBlue) : "some aren't blue";
```

Documentation does not clarify whether the predicate is evaluated for rest of elements if one results in false, but I suspect they won't be. You can trivially check the source.

If you do need it to be evaluated for all elements then you should use `filter` and check the size of the result.

Comment: It's true. `Iterables.all` delegates to `Iterators.all`, which has the short circuit logic to return false at the first failure.